# How do you debug printable CSS?

Tags: css

I use Firebug and IE Developer Toolbar all the time to debug tricky CSS problems.  But occasionally, a tricky bug comes up that only appears when you go to print the page.

What techniques/tools do you use to diagnose problems like this?  Is there a way to get more use out of traditional CSS debugging tools in print view?

Updated: I already use a PDF printer to avoid wasting paper; my problem is that I can't right-click on the printed DOM.  Some of the other answers below are quite helpful, thanks. :-)

Comment: Better answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452713/suggestions-for-debugging-print-stylesheets

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452713/suggestions-for-debugging-print-stylesheets , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode/

Comment: See this answer for a technique that works in 2021: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58015662/8932080

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In Chrome 51:

[image: Chrome developer tools]

Open devtools (`CTRL + F12` or `CTRL + SHIFT + I`) and click on the `...` menu, click `More Tools > Rendering settings` to open the `Rendering` tab of the developer console (alternatively, if the console is open just navigate to this tab).

In that tab, select and check the box for `Emulate Media: print`.

Comment: Beware: this won't emulate things like hiding background images/colors (which the firefox answer does).

Comment: Is there a print emulator on IE?

Answer (score 84):

Just found a comment by [lee-penkman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1323161/lee-penkman) about a new feature in Firefox [here](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/12/12/debugging-print-stylesheets-now-significantly-easier-in-chrome/#comment-1394994872): Press `Shift-F2` in Firefox to open the browser console (not the javascript console), then enter `media emulate print`. Works absolutely great!

---

**Update Sept. 2018**: Starting with Firefox 62, the developer console has disappeared. There doesn't seem to be a way to activate print style emulation now.

---

**Update Nov. 2019**: It seems that in Firefox 69, there is again a new button for print style emulation. See the other answer on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58015662/195476

Comment: This worked great for me once I paid attention to what you actually said to do rather than assuming I knew. This isn't in the console in the F12 tools, it's the developer toolbar.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This is some great feature that would have solved a lot of problems that I had in the past... +1

Comment: Sadly this feature doesn't behave 100% like the actual print function. [THIS](http://i.imgur.com/94mfKAt.png) is with the `media emulate print` option enabled, while [THIS](http://i.imgur.com/SpKLdZz.png) is the actual Firefox's print preview.

Comment: On Mac: `fn+shift+F2`

Comment: But this isn't representing the real print layout?

Comment: The Developer Toolbar has been removed as of Firefox 62: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877112/firefox-57-quantum-emulate-print-styles

Comment: See the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58015662/4194079). You should consider editing your answer and redirect readers toward it.

Comment: The firefox toggle button is nowadays at Web Developer Tools - Inspector - Rules and its toolbar contains a button that looks like a paper with three lines of text. That will toggle between media screen and print. However, the only way to debug page breaks is to use print preview or print to PDF and there you cannot use inspection tools. I've found that `outline: solid red 1px` is the best tool for page break debugging.

Answer (score 23):

I use the WebDeveloper plugin and the CSS --> Display CSS by Media Type --> Print to view the CSS as it would when printed.  Firebug's inspection utilities work with the CSS as filtered by the plugin.

Comment: Sadly, that view doesn't even remotely resemble what Firefox actually prints (it seems to use screen-only styles too when printing). I didn't find any better option than frequent use of the print preview option while editing styles in Firebug.

Comment: Indeed, I think it's because there is no notion of pages... but at least, you can have a look at it without having to preview it.

Comment: It appears to use ONLY print styles. A nice trick is to not only set your specific media types, but also set all other stylesheets to media="all, print". Works for me :-)

Answer (score 9):

In Firefox 69, I found a button to simulate print media.  Just open the Developer Tools (F12) and click on Inspector. The toggle button is the leftmost icon that's in the highlighted section in the screenshot below, the one that looks like a sheet of paper.

[image]

Comment: This should be considered as the FireFox-related answer.

Comment: Yes, almost missed that little blue sheet of paper icon, thanks

Comment: click, but nothing happend

Comment: @Andrii Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 6):

I use Firefox and the [developer toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60).

I use the real time css edit tool in the task bar, it's pretty usefull to modify your css on the fly on see the results in real time.

I also use the outline feature, which the div and stuff like that on mouse over, on your website. Really helpful to find div.

For the print problem, go to CSS -> Display CSS style by media -> print

There are a lot of other tool available in this one, I probably use about 10% of it.

Try maybe you find something usefull.

Answer (score 4):

In chrome developer tools (F12 \ Ctrl(cmd on mac) + Shift + C):
In the emulation tab (From Chrome 32 onward IMHO), there is a tab for 'Media'.

There you can check the media emulation checkbox and select the media you would like to emulate ('print', 'screen' etc.)

Answer (score 3):

How about just listing your print CSS last, and removing the "print" condition from your CSS link or import statement? Then you're debugging the print CSS in the browser window.

Comment: just gotta make sure you set `#body { width: 8.5in; height:11in;}`

Comment: Brilliant idea! This was extremely effective for me

Comment: Did not work for me in Firefox v22. Looked very different than the actual print.

Comment: Worked in FF37. The print link tag is the last one in the list of css link tags. Switched the media attribute in that link tag from "print" to "screen". Left all other link tags as is.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Adobe PDF virtual printer, because it's the closest thing to a real printer you'd get, without wasting ink and paper.

Anyway, it's recommended to have a separate CSS for prints, with much simpler graphics and less of the images you use just for design purposes.

Comment: Yes, it's the separate CSS that I'm trying to debug.  (PDF printer is a good tip; I use that a lot.)

Answer (score 1):

I always used web developer toolbar (as described in the other answers), but Firebug seems to miss some styles from time to time. So I added a Bookmark to my browser and added the following Javascript as URL of the bookmark. Now I can simply switch to print style by clicking the bookmark:

```
javascript:(function(){var%20h,a,f;a=document.getElementsByTagName('link');for(h=0;h<a.length;h++){f=a[h];if(f.rel.toLowerCase().match(/stylesheet/)&&f.href&&(f.media=='print'||f.media=='screen')){var%20g=f.href.replace(/(&|%5C?)forceReload=\d+/,'');if(f.media.toLowerCase().match(/screen/))f.media="dontshow";if(f.media.toLowerCase().match(/print/))f.media="all";f.href=g+(g.match(/\?/)?'&':'?')+'forceReload='+(new%20Date().valueOf());}}})()
```

The code above finds all stylesheet links, tests if it is media=print and if so it changes it to media=all (and hides all media=screen by replacing it with media=dontshow) and reloads the stylesheets by adding a time token to the URL. The basic reload script is from someone else, I added media part.
This works great for me!

This would be the more readable version of the JavaScript URL above for explanation:

```
javascript: (function() {
    var h, a, f;
    a = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
    for (h = 0; h < a.length; h++) {
        f = a[h];
        if (f.rel.toLowerCase().match(/stylesheet/) && f.href && (f.media == 'print' || f.media == 'screen')) {
            var g = f.href.replace(/(&|\?)forceReload=\d /, '');
            if (f.media.toLowerCase().match(/screen/)) f.media = "dontshow";
            if (f.media.toLowerCase().match(/print/)) f.media = "all";
            f.href = g(g.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '?')
            'forceReload=' (new Date().valueOf());
        }
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Print to Microsoft XPS Document Writer if you don't want to pay money. Or use [SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/) if you've got the funds (free trial on site).