# How to force the CSS media type to be print but on the screen?

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to show the user how a page will look when printed, without actually asking them to click on the print button. I have the necessary media query based CSS for printing, but that will only be applied in print preview and when the page is actually printed. My requirement is to display the print formatted page in a dialog box within the app.

Comment: see this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519556/faster-way-to-develop-and-test-print-stylesheets-avoid-print-preview-every-time . I hope solve your prob.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this same requirement for a project. AFAIK this cannot be done as the @media print rule is specific for printing to low cost devices, as per the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-print/).

My workaround has been to emulate a printed paper using CSS. For instance, I created a div with a grey background and then an inner div with a white background, emulating paper. I set margins according to my print margins and placed html inside this container. This approach does not guarantee by any means a replica of what to expect when printing, since elements such as wide tables and images might make the container wider than the printed page, while a print engine could apply scaling.

Compounding these issues, it is not possible to reliably predict how print engines and printer configurations might handle page breaks. You can help with suggestive css attributes in the @media print rule, like `page-break-inside`, `page-break-before`, `page-break-after`, `widows`, and `orphans`. In my print preview div, I simply layout a continuous html within the emulation containers and make it clear to the user this is an emulation.

Comment: Thanks @jfeferman. I will wait for a couple of days to see if there are anymore ideas.