# How do I emulate a CSS print media type in Firefox Developer Edition?

Tags: css, media-queries, firefox-developer-edition, print-style, firefox-nightly

As you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI), the Developer Toolbar has been removed from the latest versions of Firefox, so I can't run a "media emulate print" command anymore. I would prefer to not have to use Chrome to debug my print styles, so is there any other way to turn on that functionality in Firefox?

Edit: the Web Developer extension is not an option because it only works with `<link>` tags that have the `media="print"` attribute -- not print media queries contained in normal CSS files.

**Before anyone marks this as a duplicate:**
I've already seen [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1113516/is-it-possible-to-view-a-page-in-firefox-using-print-media-type) (which does not apply to the current Developer Edition) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519556/faster-way-to-develop-and-test-print-stylesheets-avoid-print-preview-every-time) (which tells me how to do it in Chrome). And I don't have enough rep to do anything other than post a new question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firefox has now a simple button for print emulation: *Inspect Element*, click the page symbol (blue in the picture).

[image: Isnpect Element view]

(From
https://css-tricks.com/can-you-view-print-stylesheets-applied-directly-in-the-browser/, thanks!)

Comment: On Firefox 113, the button does almost nothing. I'd love it to switch rendering into print-media to help me fixing CSS.