# Puppeteer ignores some CSS rules to print PDF when I used the @media print

Tags: puppeteer

When I used the puppeteer to print html to pdf, I met a strange problem. I find the puppeteer always ignore some CSS rules which is in @media print.

Here is my env:

Puppeteer version: 1.11
Platform / OS version: Win10/CentOS7
Node.js version: 10.15.0

CSS codes:

```
@media print {
    .flipbook-viewport .flipbook{
        width: 794px!important;
        height: 1123px!important;
        max-height: 1123px;
        max-width: 794px;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .right-01 .image {
        width: 92%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        background-image: url('../image/content/test.png');
        height: 920px;
        /* width: 740px; */
        margin-top: 0.8rem;
    }
}
```

You can notice that I set a background-color to check the test result. In my test, when I executed puppeteer with page.emulateMedia('print'), the flipbook-viewport and flipbook's rules work fine. But the right-01 and image's didn't work.

But the funny thing is when I used the @media screen (also change the page.emulateMedia to screen) with the same rules, they all worked fine. So I think it might have some problem with puppeteer.

What is the expected result?
[good.pdf](http://www.kaol.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/good.pdf)

What happens instead?
[wrong.pdf](http://www.kaol.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/test.pdf)

Does anyone meet this problem before? How to resolve this problem? Please help.

An example of my puppeteer code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath:'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://www.kaol.org/TurnPage/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    await page.emulateMedia('print');
    await page.pdf({path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'A4', printBackground: true});
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: I've seen the similar behavior in the past and have an idea... but could you host somewhere this page to run a test on?

Comment: @Vaviloff, of course, you can use [this link](http://www.kaol.org/TurnPage/) to test. Now, I use the @media screen by setting `min-width: 1600px` to solve this problem temporarily.

Comment: Hey, that's great, can you also post the minimal example of your puppeteer code? — as I don't know which settings for print emulation you use.

Comment: @Vaviloff, I have updated an example of my code. I wanna use the `@media print` setting to control the print style. But it doesn't work. I'm looking forward to your kindly answers. Thanks.

Comment: Did U solve this? I have a problem like this with images.

Answer (score 11):

The [documentation for PDF print](https://pptr.dev/next/api/puppeteer.pdfoptions/) of puppeteer list a few possible options. Among them also `printBackground`:

> `<boolean>` Print background graphics. Defaults to false.

Try setting this to `true` to include background-graphics and -colors to your PDF-export.

Comment: Thanks. But I already set the `printBackground` to `true`. You can check the pdf files which I converted. The color and graphics is fine. The problem is the picture's size isn't work.

Answer (score 6):

From what I can tell, Puppeteer uses the screen dimensions of your machine to determine the width and height to first generate the page and then print that page to PDF, so the machine's display values are used when `background-size: 100%` are used.

Ýou can pass the dimensions explicitly:

```
@media print {
    @page {
        size: A4 portrait;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

And to your `body` add the size in paper dimension sizes so they aren't derived from the system:

```
background-size: 21cm 29.7cm;
```

Then pass the `preferCSSPageSize` and `printBackground` flags:

```
const pdf = await page.pdf({
    preferCSSPageSize: true,
    printBackground: true
});
```

It also seems `format: 'A4'` at best does nothing when your `@page` has dimensions and at worst possibly overrides part of your css, so I'd leave it out entirely.

Answer (score 3):

For me none of the solutions I found on stackoverflow worked, I almost "lost hope". But after playing around with all the info I found it turned out that you need only 2 things:

1. the `printBackground` option has to be set to TRUE, e.g.:
   `page.pdf({ path: "./my.pdf", printBackground: true });`
2. add to your background or color values `!important`, e.g.:

```
p {
  color: red !important; 
  background: blue !important; 
}
```

That's it.

P.S. I have currently Puppeteer v5.5.0.

Comment: !important + printBackground works like a charm. The only small improvement I would recommend is to add important rule only for printing option e.g if you use scss.
```@media print {
  p {   color: red !important;  }
 }```

Comment: Does not work for me (v 13.0.2) =( What fixed it was using `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact`

Answer (score 1):

`puppeteer` is just a library to drive Chrome/Chromium, so if anything goes wrong while using it, our best bet is to open Chromium with `puppeteer.launch({headless:false})` and debug there. (However printing to PDF is not supported in headful mode now, so we may just use a full browser)

There's a built-in support for debugging print mode in Chrome DevTools, [here's how to turn it on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18119733/2715393).

Having turned that on, after page reload I saw a 404 in the network tab: that [background image](http://www.kaol.org/image/content/20181206picture1.png) could not be found. It happened because when you had moved @media print **out of** stylesheet into the main page, the relative link `../image/content/20181206picture1.png` became broken (before it was relative to stylesheet location but now it is relative to the page location).

So after fixing this link [here's the resulting pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcBLA.png) which I believe is correct. Can't comment on width/height though, there could be something else in your stylesheets affecting that.

Comment: Thanks. I know the background image broken problem. The point is I want to get the web content to fill up the whole A4 page when I print it(check the good.pdf in this post). So I try to use the `@Media print` to control it.