# Mysterious whitespace at bottom HTML Print

Tags: html, css, media-queries, chromium, puppeteer

I am working on app, which used to create some reports.

App allows user to choose Page size from A3, A4 and letter.

I'm Using @media query for Printing. I found the mysterious whitespace at bottom of the page. I want to get ride of that.

Here is my Snippets.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>report</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/style.css">

    <style>
        @media print {
            @page {
                margin: 0 !important;
                size: A3 portrait;
            }

            body {
                height: 100% !important;
                margin: 0 !important;
                padding: 0 !important;
            }

            .page {
                margin: 0 !important;
                margin-bottom: 0 !important;
                page-break-after: always !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="report">
        <div class="page cover A3 portrait">
            <div>
                <div class="coverpage">
                    <div class="artA">
                        <div class="logo"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="infoBox">
                        <div class="artB"></div>
                        <div class="elements">
                            <div class="title">
                                <span>Report Name</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="createdBy">
                                <span>John Doe</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="createdDate">
                                <span>26-08-19 22.16.55.348 IST</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="dateRange">
                                <p>Date Range:&nbsp;<span>now-2y</span> <span>now</span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div class="page A3 potrait ">
                <div class="pageHeader">
                    <div class="headerContent"><span>Page Header</span></div>
                </div>
                <div style="height: 100%;">
                    <div cdkdroplist="" class="col-md-12  layout gridster cdk-drop-list fit" id="cdk-drop-list-16"
                        style="padding: 10px 20px;">
                        <div class="   cssTransform  "
                            style="position: absolute; touch-action: none; overflow: hidden; display: block; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); width: 536px; height: 490.667px;"
                            id="BarChart_0_0">
                            <div class="chartHeading" style="cursor:pointer;" id="BarChart_0_0_title"> BarChart_0_0
                            </div>
                            <div class="svg-container" id="BarChart_0_0_cc"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="   cssTransform  "
                            style="position: absolute; touch-action: none; overflow: hidden; display: block; transform: translate3d(546px, 0px, 0px); width: 536px; height: 490.667px; margin-right: 20px;"
                            id="HorizontalBarChart_0_1">
                            <div class="chartHeading" style="cursor:pointer;" id="HorizontalBarChart_0_1_title">
                                HorizontalBarChart_0_1 </div>
                            <div class="svg-container" id="HorizontalBarChart_0_1_cc"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="   cssTransform  "
                            style="position: absolute; touch-action: none; overflow: hidden; display: block; transform: translate3d(0px, 1001px, 0px); width: 536px; height: 490.667px; margin-bottom: 10px;"
                            id="PieChart_0_2">
                            <div class="chartHeading" style="cursor:pointer;" id="PieChart_0_2_title"> PieChart_0_2
                            </div>
                            <div class="svg-container" id="PieChart_0_2_cc"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="   cssTransform  "
                            style="position: absolute; touch-action: none; overflow: hidden; display: block; transform: translate3d(546px, 501px, 0px); width: 536px; height: 490.667px; margin-right: 20px;"
                            id="RingChart_0_3">
                            <div class="chartHeading" style="cursor:pointer;" id="RingChart_0_3_title"> RingChart_0_3
                            </div>
                            <div class="svg-container" id="RingChart_0_3_cc"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class=""
                            style="transform: translate3d(0px, 1001px, 0px); width: 536px; height: 490.667px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pageFooter">
                    <div class="footerContent"><span></span>&nbsp; <span> Page Footer</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

style.css

```css
.A4 {
    width: 210mm !important;
  height: 297mm !important;
}
.A4.landscape {
    width: 297mm !important;
    height: 210mm !important;
}

.A3 {
    width: 297mm !important;
  height: 420mm !important;
}
.A3.landscape {
    width: 420mm !important;
    height: 297mm !important;
}

.letter {
    width: 216mm !important;
  height: 279mm !important;
}
.letter.landscape {
  width: 279mm !important;
    height: 216mm !important;
}

.bodyCanvas{
  height: 100%;
}


.page{
  margin:20px auto;
  position: relative;
  width:fit-content;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

}

.pageHeader{
  background: #324156;
  margin-top: 0px !important;
  height: 40px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.pageFooter{
  height:40px;
  background: #324156;
  bottom: 0;
}

.headerContent {
    padding:10px;
}

.footerContent {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

[image]

Whitespace after the footer div with Print as shown in attached image.

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate print mode by clicking opening DevTools main menu, picking More Tools > Rendering, and then setting it to "print". Then you'll be able to use the regular element inspector to click on that padding (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519556/faster-way-to-develop-and-test-print-stylesheets-avoid-print-preview-every-time#18119733) for visual guide).

[testing the provided HTML+CSS alone, I do not get the demonstrated padding]

Comment: Hi, Padding shown in PDF or Print Preview. Not shown in DevTool with print emulation.