# jQuery print() div not rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using jQuery print() to print the div packingList. It did work but the first time I clicked the print button, the div is blank, only second time I clicked it the div rendered. May I know why does this happen? Also, When I use google chrome, it did come out print preview before print.... But when I use firefox or IE, there is no print preview....Any ideas how to enable print preview prior to print? A
js

```
     $( "a" ).attr( "href", "javascript:void( 0 )" ).click(function(){
                 // Print the DIV.
                $( ".packingList" ).print();
                // Cancel click event.
                 return( false );
     });
```

jquery.print.js

```
// Create a jquery plugin that prints the given element.
jQuery.fn.print = function() {
    // NOTE: We are trimming the jQuery collection down to the
    // first element in the collection.
    if (this.size() > 1) {
        this.eq(0).print();
        return;
    } else if (!this.size()) {
        return;
    }

    // ASSERT: At this point, we know that the current jQuery
    // collection (as defined by THIS), contains only one
    // printable element.

    // Create a random name for the print frame.
    var strFrameName = ("printer-" + (new Date()).getTime());

    // Create an iFrame with the new name.
    var jFrame = $("<iframe name='" + strFrameName + "'>");

    // Hide the frame (sort of) and attach to the body.
    jFrame
    .css("width", "1px")
    .css("height", "1px")
    .css("position", "absolute")
    .css("left", "-9999px")
    .appendTo($("body:first"))
    ;

    // Get a FRAMES reference to the new frame.
    var objFrame = window.frames[strFrameName];

    // Get a reference to the DOM in the new frame.
    var objDoc = objFrame.document;

    // Grab all the style tags and copy to the new
    // document so that we capture look and feel of
    // the current document.

    // Create a temp document DIV to hold the style tags.
    // This is the only way I could find to get the style
    // tags into IE.
    var jStyleDiv = $("<div>").append(
    $("style").clone()
    );

    // Write the HTML for the document. In this, we will
    // write out the HTML of the current element.
    objDoc.open();
    objDoc.write("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">");
    objDoc.write("<html>");
    objDoc.write("<body>");
    objDoc.write("<head>");
    objDoc.write("<title>");
    objDoc.write(document.title);
    objDoc.write("</title>");
    objDoc.write(jStyleDiv.html());
    objDoc.write( "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://localhost:81/travelwithus/css/main.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"print\" />" );
    objDoc.write("</head>");
    objDoc.write(this.html());
    objDoc.write("</body>");
    objDoc.write("</html>");
    objDoc.close();

    // Print the document.
    objFrame.focus();
    objFrame.print();

    // Have the frame remove itself in about a minute so that
    // we don't build up too many of these frames.
    setTimeout(
    function() {
        jFrame.remove();
    },
    (60 * 1000)
    );
}
```

Comment: did you check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565541/resize-page-contents-to-fit-on-one-print-page

Comment: I think it's because IE has no preview feature.

Comment: is there any alternative I can do for this?