# Printing html tables that fit to page

Tags: php, html, css, angularjs

So I have a report that generates multiple tables from a database, and grouping them by 'owner' creating a new table for each 'owner'.  It does this dynamically using Angular/PHP/Js.

In the print preview I want each table to have it's own page(tables shouldn't really go beyond the length of a page) so I added the page-break-after value to each table.

My issue now is that the tables are cut off. I have the option for landscape, but unfortunately they are long tables, and still get cut off.

- I am looking for a solution for the tables to be re-sized when
  printed out.
- [Here is a sample of the table being cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssn9T.png)

I have searched both here, google and w3 for a method that re-sizes the tables to fit the print preview but so far have had no luck.

Suggestions?

Comment: Did adding page-break-after change anything with respect to tables cutting off?  Wouldn't they have cut off anyway?

Comment: I was just noting that, cause each table on a new page is part of the constraint.

Comment: you might need to install something that generates a PDF of this report, if you really want this to work consistently.

Comment: I think you are right. This is probably beyond the scope, (or would really be a messy tweak with css media).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a media query for this.  Target @print and do some trial and error to get it to look correctly when viewing in print preview.  I'm assuming you haven't already done this.

https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: You could equally use the Chrome inspector to debug : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452713/suggestions-for-debugging-print-stylesheets as it will be much easier than with the print preview.

Comment: This is very close to what I needed.  But because of the size of the tables, long or wide (due to contents) I should be looking to generate PDFs instead.