# How to generate pdf using html in asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to generate pdf in a3 page by inputting Html containing CSS and some jquery generated range bars using asp.net MVC i tried itextsharp but there is img tag error and no solution work regarding it.
i tried jspdf but it not includes css.

Following solution i tried for below error:

```
<img src="assd.jpg"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use rotativa to generate pdf documents from views, I’ve used it in the past with great results - look here for a walkthrough

> https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-rotativa-easy-way-to-create-pdf-and-image-files/

Comment: Is that a specific css class or all css not working?  I’ve not had a problem when using it in the past.  There is another question related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37025246/rotativa-mvc-not-loading-css-or-images-on-pdf

Comment: all CSS not working it generates the pdf with the only logo in my HTML in the center of pdf.

Comment: Can you post the html your trying you use,

Comment: The error dump isn’t happy with the IMG element, have you check this is correct?

Comment: yes i know i also try some fixes like closing image tag like this  : <img/> and also <img></img> but no effect.