# urls being shown after links when printing web page

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with a site that I've created. When the page is printed (as in command+p) it prints out the urls of hyperlinks as part of the page content. I'm guessing this is using the :after pseudo class to add the href attribute after hyperlinks, but I can't find any instance in my stylesheets where it might be doing this.

I'm including the modernizer script in my page so it might be caused by something that script is doing.

It's difficult to debug this problem. Is there a way to spoof @media so that any stylesheets and scripts think I'm using print rather than screen?

UPDATE: I found the css that was causing this, but I could have found it faster if I had the use of firebug, which brings me back to my original question: How can I debug the print stylesheet using firebug. Do you just change the media attribute on the print stylesheet `<link`/> or is there a way to spoof it with the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Web-Developer plugin allow you to do that.

http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/

Install it -> Look at toolbar -> CSS -> Display CSS by Media Type

Also, similar question here : [How do you debug printable CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726825/how-do-you-debug-printable-css)