# Firebug not working in print preview

Tags: javascript, css, html, firefox, firebug

I am writing print CSS for my site. Now the problem is that Firebug or similar devtools don't work in the browser's print preview. So it's hard for me to detect the problem.

Does anyone have a suggestion how to debug CSS print layout?

Answer (score 3):

The Chrome DevTools can do this by changing the *Media CSS* option in the *Emulation* menu.

Check this out: [Suggestions for debugging print stylesheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452713/suggestions-for-debugging-print-stylesheets)

On Firefox you must select the *Display CSS by Media Type* option with the [Web Developer add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/web-developer/) and then Firebug will work. There's also an [enhancement request for Firebug to support switching between different media types](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=3056).

Check this out, too: [How do you debug printable CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726825/how-do-you-debug-printable-css)