# Print preview shows one div in wrong position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a plot in javascript and wanted to show a legend for the plot overlapping the plot. The function creating this plot doesn't allow an overlapping legend directly, but it leaves you the possibility to place the legend in a separate div. So I made these two divs:

```
<div id="ContainingLegend">
  <div id="VariablePlotLegend">
  </div
</div>
```

So the legend will the placed in the div VariablePlotLegend.

Here are my two relevant CSS parts:

```
#ContainingLegend{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -73px; 
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#VariablePlotLegend{
    padding: 3px;
    border-color: #004790;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}
```

On screen the legend is shown perfectly. On print it is shown below the plot on the left, in all black with no border etc. Why?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Unfortunately not :-( The plot is created using R, Shiny and Rstudio and the HTML source code somehow doesn't contain everything

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding the problem. Specifically, I have no idea what you mean by on screen or on print. Your negative margin-top might be at fault though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margins aren't what I would personally choose for printing.

Try something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class='container'>
  <figure id='MyPlotChart'>
    <!-- Whatever your plot chart HTML is -->
    <figcaption id='ContainingLegend'>
      <div id='VariablePlotLegend'>
        <!-- Legend HTML -->
      </div>
   </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#MyPlotChart {
  position: relative;
}
#ContainingLegend {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

This gives you the benefit of being semantically correct with your HTML, and `figure` and `figcaption` already have the relationship you're after as far as positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the print css, maybe one of the tools you are using it trying to make it look better for printing.  [debugging print css with chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/726852/3042939)