# Chrome rendering of a print layout broken

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, safari

I have a webpage that's being printed correctly in Safari but not in Chrome. In Chrome, only the last line of text is appearing. You can select the hidden text though.

I am using a separate CSS for print styling.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[Print layout rendering in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxQ7T.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is this answer which can help you debug the css written under @print media:

[How do you debug printable CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726825/how-do-you-debug-printable-css/58015662#58015662)

Did not find anything similar in chrome, but something similar mat exist.

If you can share the link of your HTML page, I can have a better understanding of the root cause, but it seems like one or more of the below:

1. some other element is present above the text(position absolute or fixed)
2. font color is white
3. presence of a float element